# RichTextField django + html

Tags: python, html, css, django, backend

Has anyone had experience working with RichTextField? When I add an entry in the admin panel, the code there is highlighted and its background is gray, but when output to the html template there is no design. Here are my settings:

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['Image', 'CodeSnippet'],
        ],
        'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet',
        'width': '550px',
    },
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl9tl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2vTB.png)

I didn't add any plugins except ckeditor itself